# Is a calling a function pointer through a hash_map<string, fnPtr> more efficient or better style than multiple if/else if/else statements in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, coding-style

I was going to make a `switch` statement, but then realized that it can't be done against a `string`.  So I then wrote an `if`/`else if`/`else` statement and then realised that I shouldn't make my function so long.  So then I was going to put function calls inside the body of each cascading `if` block and thought it might be better to use a `hash_map`/`unordered_map` to a set of function pointers.

My questions are:

1. Would it be more efficient to use a hash_map to point at the function to use and call it that way?

   IIRC, a map should be close to O(1), where as a cascading if would need to test all the way down until it finds a match thus being O(N).  However, at what point (what N) does the O(1) out pace the O(N) nature using maps with string keys?
2. Is it better coding style?

   Since I'm reducing encapsulating specific code into smaller functions that are specific to the operation needed to be done, I think that this would be true.  I know that it is more of an opinion question, but as a community, I think that this is still a valid one.

Comment: Retrieval in a map is O(log(n)), not O(1) (maybe you are thinking about a hashmap?). See e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Updating question

Comment: Can you use a base class and virtual functions to eliminate the need for the <string, fnPtr> pair?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: No, it is based on parsed data.  This is the parse recognition point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Depends on a lot of things-  how big your table is, how bad the performance hit of a cache miss in the branch predictor is, how much you can optimize the most common cases first, how intensive your hash function is and whether or not those hashes are cached, how many collisions do you get and how you remap those collisions.  It will tend to be the hash, but may not be for some cases.
2. The map is cleaner.  Its much easier to understand, and you won't have someone decide to throw in special case logic in 1 branch out of 15 in the if statement which then gets lost in debugging and maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be more efficient to use a hash_map to point at the function to use and call it that way?

I don't think efficiency is going to be an issue for either approach, unless you plan to have a really large amount of strings/function pointers (in which case your suggestion is the *only* viable option).

> Is it better coding style?

I would say so. It certainly looks a lot cleaner and it's straightforward to understand.